# How can i POST the NSMutable Array to php file in objective c

Tags: php, iphone, xml, nsmutablearray

I am new to iPhone Programming.

I am have one `NSMutableArray` i want to `POST` that array to server's `php` file and update my server's `xml` file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried something for it??

Answer (score 1):

May you need this code ..

declare a reference of *NSURLConnection* **postConnection* in .h and make it property and synthesize in .m file...

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"yourPhpUrl.php"]];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSMutableDictionary *jsonDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[jsonDict setValue:yourArray forKey:@"userName"];
NSLog(@"JSON Dict: %@",jsonDict);//Check your array here...


NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonDict options:kNilOptions error:nil];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"JSON String: %@",jsonString); //Check your post String here...

[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

[request setValue:@"json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Data-Type"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [jsonData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody: jsonData];

self.postConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:true];
```

may this will help you

Comment: It's fine. Instead of creating json object. How we create the XML object.

Comment: why you need to create xml object..?

Comment: can you please give me server side coding for this?